# Id in (list) condition always return true in if else statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to have one if else condition in a procedure -

```
IF (@currentid in (select a_id from table_1 group by b_id)) THEN
SET @value = 1;
ELSE
SET @value = @value + 1;
END IF;
```

I am using this in a while loop where the value of @currentid keeps changing.But here I am not getting the expected behaviour.
Even though some @currentid is not present in the list obtained from

```
select a_id from table_1 group by b_id
```

the condition comes to be true always.

Can you please help me to understand why the if condition is not failing ?

Comment: Can you give us an example when it doesn't work ?

Comment: For example - 
select a_id from table_1 group by b_id returns the following ids - 
1, 3, 5, 7...

And in the while loop value of currentid changes as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ..

But the condition becomes true for all the values of currentid even though it should be false for values 2, 4, 6, ...